# Angular 2 : Integrate bootstrap admin template with scss style

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, sass, ssas, integration

I'm trying to find a free bootstrap template with scss style and integrate it with angular project. can some one tell  me the right way to do it. 
I found this template on github but I didn't undrestand the way to do it :

https://github.com/pratikborsadiya/vali-admin

thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I prefer use materializecss of google because it is a frame work which is made for angular its on scss as well and temple-ting engine is well formed 
http://demo.geekslabs.com/materialize-v1.0/layout-fullscreen.html